# How to get a page with only a search box and a logo to rank in search engines?

Tags: seo, ranking, thin-content

I have a webpage that has its `index.php` page that looks like like Google's home page. I mean it only has a search input box and a logo on it. It is not a Google like search engine but it is a search engine for my database that users can search for something included in my site. I want to keep it like that and I believe it looks simple and good but I'm having difficulty with SEO.

As it has a lack of content, I'm having difficulty with matching meta description and page title to the contents which would increase my ranking. I don't want to use hidden elements to spam inside `<h1>`'s and words which are going to lead me to be blacklisted on Search Engines.

Is there any advice that would be helpful for me?

Comment: Is it _obvious_ what the purpose of your "search engine" is to the casual visitor? Is there enough information on the page to explain its purpose?

Comment: @MrWhite Actually my website is online javascript editor and with search engine you search for written js codes.

Comment: So, are you saying you don't have any additional content on the page? You literally just have the search box and a logo, as you mentioned?

Comment: The title is not a meta element.   It doesn't use the `<meta>` tag and it is not invisible to users.   It is used by the browser in tabs and in the window title.   You should call it the "page title" rather than a "meta title".  I've edited your question to make that correction.

Comment: Search engines facilitate search for people who are looking for information. If there is no information for users on the page, how do you expect people to find the page in a search engine? Short answer? You can't. Sorry. That is just not how search engines work. If there is content on your site, then link to your search page. Short of that, you can always add content.

Comment: @closetnoc "can't" is pretty strongly worded.  Google ranks #1 if you search for "Google".   It you just want to rank for your brand it should be do-able.  Ranking for other things is harder.  Even Google doesn't rank #1 for "search engine" on Google.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Please do not confuse rank with a page being found in search. Google is not a fair comparison. It is a well established brand. For a page without content to found in search you would need something very substantial. A lot of links could do it. So can branding. However short of that, how is a search engine to match a search query to essentially a blank page? It can't. Not without clues such as image alt text and form elements. Even that is not enough in a highly competitive world wide ontology of documents. Links to the page can give clues if the content supports it. Cheers!

Comment: Short of that, "can't" is the right word.   If you want to brand it and get lots of links, then it can be done.

Comment: The issue is this, my webpage is a online js editor and addition to this it has a search engine to search for published codes. As you know other JS editors dont have contents in their page. Code editor is code editor and you can only see editor panel and output iframe. I know that i cannot add content into editor.php page there is no space which lets me to use index.php to use for google rank increase. Dont really matter if people enter index.php or editor.php as long as they enter the site.

Answer (score 3):

If you enjoy the simplicity of your web page, but want your website to be more SEO-friendly, you could make a `div` that contains your current content that is `width:100%; height:100%` of the user's viewport.

Then you can add an arrow or link towards the bottom of the page that a user can click if he/she wants to learn more. This link could dynamically scroll down to additional content.

Here's an example: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/

This way, user's can decide if they want to see more on an individual basis, and search engines will pick up more content.

Comment: This looks the only solution i believe. I will consider this thank you.

Comment: Hey again I came up with a solution. Do you this this will count as spam and blacklisted? The one with codes http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=9e342ecc0a4911257772c84260e10911 and the one with full page http://cr8code.co/fullview.php?workid=9e342ecc0a4911257772c84260e10911 I added a more button to the bottom when you click it the div with bottom:-100vh comes over.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to rank a page on Google if that page only has a search bar. Google likes to rank content. And doing anything to try and game Googlebot into thinking that you have more content than you already do is risky as Googlebot has algorithms in place to detect this behavior.

If you'd like to have a better chance at ranking this page, you could add more content below the fold, so that when users enter the page they just see the search bar but if they scroll down they see more content. Google will rank sites higher based on what's above the fold, but the added content below it will give you a boost as well. Perhaps you could try to add daily news thumbnails and titles.

If you're worried about page load speed due to the added content, you could load the content through ajax so that the search bar will load at the same speed as before.

Comment: You mean to run ajax if the page is scrolled? Will it be triggered by search engine bots?

Comment: You can use onload with ajax so that the content loads after the window loads. Googlebot can crawl onload ajax content